# MVC ActionFilterAttribute DbContext Disposed Solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, actionfilterattribute

I currently have the following ActionFilterAttribute in my MVC project.  It works fine for the first request, but subsequent requests return a message that the DbContext is disposed.

```
public class PermissionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationGroupManager _groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();
    private readonly ActionPermissionManager _permissionManager = new ActionPermissionManager();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            #region Preventing caching of ajax request in IE browser

            response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            #endregion Preventing caching of ajax request in IE browser
        }
        var currentAreaName = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
        var currentActionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var currentControllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

        if (!_groupManager.UserHasAdministratorAccess(userId))
        {
            if (!_permissionManager.HasPermission((currentAreaName == null ? String.Empty : currentAreaName.ToString()), currentControllerName, currentActionName, userId))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "Login" } });
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I've read enough that realize this is an issue with the following change that was introduced in MVC3

> Breaking Changes: In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, action filters
>   are create per request except in a few cases. This behavior was never
>   a guaranteed behavior but merely an implementation detail and the
>   contract for filters was to consider them stateless. In ASP.NET MVC 3,
>   filters are cached more aggressively. Therefore, any custom action
>   filters which improperly store instance state might be broken.

I'm unsure of how best to resolve this issue.  I considered moving my two private readonly fields into the OnActionExecuting piece which I believe would solve the issue, but I'm worried about multi-threading and if there would be issues with that implementation.

It seems many people have got around this problem using Castle Windsor or Ninject but those are outside my level of expertise and even after going through the Windsor tutorial (https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-intro.md) I'm unable to understand what exactly I need to do.

Comment: In your case using Castle Windsor or Ninject is like trying to hit a pin with the Thor's hammer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your two fields, which you initialize and keep:

```
private readonly ApplicationGroupManager _groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();
private readonly ActionPermissionManager _permissionManager = new ActionPermissionManager();
```

Presumably at least one of these has a DbContext instance which is also initialized in a constructor or in a field/property initializer. I obviously don't know the internal workings of these classes, but it doesn't look like they're used by any other methods. They really should be declared within the method instead of class fields:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ApplicationGroupManager groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();
    ActionPermissionManager permissionManager = new ActionPermissionManager();

    // The rest of your code here
}
```

This will also fix the error you're seeing. Since the Manager instances (and their DbContext members) are re-initialized for each request, you don't have to worry about the code trying to re-use disposed instances.

Comment: This is the solution I'm leaning towards as I said in my question.  However, is there any concerns about the variables since there is only one instance of an ActionFilterAttribute per decorated method?  Could two simultaneous requests to the same method will result in issues with these variables?

Comment: That's really a question for you..they're your classes. If they keep static or global state internally, then yes - that might be an issue. As long as your classes are designed well and explicitly declare dependencies, then you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a proxy filter class which will instantiate and wire the actual filter.

```
public class PermissionFilterProxy : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // create and wire the actual filter
            // so in this way its lifetime is handled by us
            PermissionFilter permissionFilter = new PermissionFilter();
            permissionFilter.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        }
    }
```

Instead of `PermissionFilter`, you will configure (add) now this proxy.

Comment: This is an interesting solution... Thanks.

Comment: Note that this still results in re-initializing your manager classes per-request. It is effectively the same effect as my solution below, but this solution is better if you can't modify the underlying filter (or you just really don't want to for some reason).